# JavaScript CallBack Function ..ish issue

Tags: javascript, callback

So I was doing some practice about callback function and I wanted to try it out in my own was and use it with a setTimeout Method and to my surprise, it didn't work as expected.. Pls what am i doing wrong here.

```js
function first(number, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(number);
  }, 5);
  callback();
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first(1, second);
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: 4ms is the minimum time for settimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing `setTimeout` and `callback` at the same time. Because JavaScript is single-threaded, it doesn't wait for `setTimeout` to complete before executing the next statement.

That's why, `2` prints immediately, and then `1` prints after a delay of 5 milliseconds.

If you want to print `1` first, then you need to call the `callback` function in the callback of `setTimeout`. This ensures that the `console.log(number)` executes prior to calling the `callback` (which prints `2`).

```js
function first(number, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(number);
    callback();
  }, 5);
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first(1, second);
```

Answer (score 0):

As 31piy already said, `setTimeout()` and `callback()` are being executed at the same time. Your code *first* schedules a function execution at 5ms from now, and then *immediately* runs another function that logs `2` to the console.

You can achieve the expected result in a couple of similar ways, I'll show one:

```js
function first(number,callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, 5);
  
  console.log(number);
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first(1, second);

//Here, you immediately print the number 1 and schedule the number 2.
```